# MPLAB, trying to clear a bit but it remains 1

Tags: interrupt, pic, mplab

I'm using MPLAB to program PIC16F84A for my project. I have an assembly code where RB4-7 bits are connected to buttons and hence used as inputs. An interrupt subroutine is implemented to handle any new interrupt (when a button is pressed). Everything works fine, when a button is pressed the pic goes to the specified subroutine. But now when I'm in the subroutine I have to clear the flag (INTCON - RBIF) but it's not being cleared, yet clearing any other bit in the INTCON register works fine. So what should I do?

Here is my code:

```
        ORG     0X00
        GOTO    START
        ORG     0x04
        BTFSC   INTCON,RBIF
        GOTO    RBX_INT
START   CLRF    PORTA
        MOVLW   B'10001000'
        MOVWF   INTCON
        BSF     STATUS,RP0
        CLRF    TRISA
        MOVLW   B'11110000'
        MOVWF   TRISB
        MOVLW   B'10000111'
        MOVWF   OPTION_REG 
        BCF     STATUS,RP0
MAIN    GOTO    MAIN
```

And this is my subroutine:

```
RBX_INT BCF     INTCON,RBIF
        MOVLW   D'156'
        CALL    DELAY
        RETFIE
```

Comment: If this is an "interrupt on change", you need to actually **read** the port, even if you don't need to know the state. If you don't do that, the logic that fires the interrupt will continue firing.

Comment: @RogerRowland Yes that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the bit right before you return from interrupt, otherwise a new interrupt can already happen while in the `delay` loop and `RBIF` will be cleared again. This happens because buttons bounce ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce ).

Also, the datasheet states:

> The input pins (of RB7:RB4)
>   are  compared  with  the  old  value  latched  on  the  last
>   read  of  PORTB.  The  “mismatch”  outputs  of  RB7:RB4
>   are  OR’ed  together  to  generate  the  RB  Port  Change
>   Interrupt with flag bit RBIF (INTCON<0>).

This means you have to read `PORTB` before clearing `RBIF` to update the latched value.

```
RBX_INT 

    MOVFW   PORTB        ;Read PORTB to update the latch.
    MOVLW   D'156'
    CALL    DELAY
    BCF     INTCON,RBIF  ;Clear interrupt flag as close as possible to RETFIE.
    RETFIE
```

Also, you should read up about context saving/restoring for interrupt service routines. For this example it matters not, because the main loop is doing nothing but because a interrupt can happen at any moment it should take care to save all registers and resources it uses and restore them before exiting the interrupt to prevent corrupting any data/state from the main codepath.

See section

> 6.9
>   Context Saving During Interrupts

In the PIC16F84A datasheet.

Comment: The delay is already taking care of the de-bouncing effect. And I already did what you are suggesting but it didn't work.

Comment: As soon as you clear RBIF any activity on PORTB will set it again in hardware. The delay only helps when performed before clearing RBIF.

Comment: Yes what you're saying is correct, but that's not my problem. The flag is not being set to zero. I'm using the stimulus to trigger the interrupt and I'm viewing the bits at every step, but still RBIF is not cleared.

Comment: @mhmdhsenkamal : I managed to reproduce your problem and fix it, post updated.